# Выскакивает непонятная ошибка React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Line 34:  'deletePersonHandler' is not defined  no-undef 
Line 40:  'showUsers' is not defined            no-undef
Line 45:  'render' is not defined
```

Не могу найти ошибки и понять тоже. В скринах код. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Скобку не закрыли фигурную для SwitchName

Comment: Появляется следующая ошибка:   });
  20 |   }
> 21 |     const person = {
     |           ^
  22 |       ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
  23 |     }

Comment: А в редакторе кода указывается, что const может использоваться только в TS-файле